# Получение ChatID и отправка его пользователю в Telegram-bot

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Мне нужно, чтобы после того, как пользователь начал чат с ботом, ему отправлялся его `chatID`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение. Нужно сначала привязываем через метод SetWebhook бота к нашему файлу-обработчику (api.telegram.org/bot<Токен>/setWebhook?url=<Ссылка до php файла>)
Потом пишем обработчик. Вот код:

```
    $access_token = '<Токен>';
$api = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $access_token;


$output = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
$chat_id = $output['message']['chat']['id'];
$first_name = $output['message']['chat']['first_name'];
$message = $output['message']['text'];
switch($message) {
case '/start':
sendMessage($chat_id, "Ваш cID" . $chat_id);
break;
}
function sendMessage($chat_id, $message) {
  file_get_contents($GLOBALS['api'] . '/sendMessage?chat_id=' . $chat_id . '&text=' . urlencode($message));
}
```

Этот код отвечает на команду /start и отправляет пользователю его chatid.